# Borders only appear on the outside so one black border around the whole thing

Tags: css, html, html-table, border

Here is the HTML below for the table. Table  one is the entire `div` I'm trying to get all of the borders to be solid like a normal bordered tabled in Excel etc. But it's only appearing outside of the whole box.

And here is the HTML and CSS below: may have added extra useless stuff fairly new to tables.

```css
#table-one {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 290px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #dbdbdb;
}

#table-one table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 6px;
  border-spacing: 25px 10px;
}

#table-one th {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "calibri light";
}

#table-one td {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: calibri;
}
```

```html
<div id="table-one">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>SAMPLE TEXT</th>
      <th>SAMPLE TEXT</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `th, td {border:...}` did not work ?

Comment: thank you so much it was just those small commas i missed and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set he border using css

```
#table-one td,#table-one th{
border:1px solid red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lrw9sqk7/1/)